# Count number of rows in dataframe to determine number of events at time and date?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to determine the number of times a certain event occurred within a timeframe.

For the following data:

`Date   | Time (in 24 hour format) | didEventHappen
1/1/15   1130                        Yes
1/1/15   1145                        Yes
1/1/15   1215                        Yes
1/2/15   1030                        Yes
1/2/15   1145                        Yes
1/2/15   1015                        Yes`

I want the output to be:

`Date   | Time (hour in 24 hour format)| EventCount
1/1/15   11                                  2
1/1/15   12                                  1 
1/2/15   10                                  2
1/2/15   11                                  1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `groupby` with `str` slice

```
df['didEventHappen'].eq('Yes').groupby([df.Date,df.Time.astype(str).str[:2]]).sum().reset_index()
Out[62]: 
     Date Time  didEventHappen
0  1/1/15   11             2.0
1  1/1/15   12             1.0
2  1/2/15   10             2.0
3  1/2/15   11             1.0
```